# is it possible to replace a javascript file in the network or sources tab of chrome

Tags: mongodb, google-chrome, firefox, meteor, data-recovery

If an webapp I am running did a GET on a javascript file but I wanted to intercept that GET and provide a different javascript file could I do that?

What would be the easiest method?

To give a frame of a reference I am writing a meteor application and the server database got torched. My only hope seems to be to take a cached version of the application.js and inject it because I believe mostly everything can be rebuilt from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the existing JavaScript code.

Not sure how to replace the JavaScript file.

Press F12 it bring the developer tools at bottom of your page .

Go to resource and select your JavaScript file

It will open inside editor(right side) there you can modify your script.

[image]